# Can you tweak or customize Spotlight to find first specific files and folders?

Tags: spotlight

For example, I have two folders named `Edit` but the one I use most frequently, shows up second on Spotlight.
Can you anyhow influence the precedence and importance of found files in Spotlight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. At one point, Spotlight would learn from your choices, but that functionality seems to have been lost in the most recent version.

You could get the functionality you want with an App Launcher like Alfred, or Quicksilver.

Answer (score 1):

You can order in which Spotlight search results appear by dragging (any checked) categories listed in the Spotlight preference pane (accessible from System Preferences).

Answer (score 1):

You can place spotlight comments in the specific file's information. If you search this comment, you will find your specific file, given that this comment is unique...